# Visual studio stopped displaying stylesheets asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

So I'm working on a project now and I got a big problem. I don't even know if I did something or what, but basically the stylesheets stopped working completely. Yesterday when I was working on it it was fine, i close it, then open it again today and it stopped displaying correctly. It looks like this now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbdUF.png)

I use the template thats provided so I just open a new project to see where I could break something but the site master file where the css is located is the same.

Comment: Check into your console network tab, why it's not loading...

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just stopped working

Comment: *It stopped working* It should have a reason to stop working...Did you check at network tab, css file is loading or not?

Comment: Ok i found an error, I had added something to the css which I now deleted. The styles are showing fine in visual studio but when I debug and run it in a browser it still doesn't work

Comment: @Mateusz: Try to clear your browser caching.

Comment: Phew, seems to be fixed, I clicked refresh linked browsers and it fixed it... must have been cached or something

Comment: That was not *or something*, it was your browser cache, and cache clear page refresh

Comment: inspect element and check for 404 errors on the css link tags. that will give u some clues